# Игра "крестики-нолики". Выдает ошибку при вводе в первый и второй столбцы

Tags: c++

```c++
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

char name1[30];
char name2[30];
char table[3][3];
bool step;

void instructions() {
  cout << "\t\t***Хрестики-нолики***\n\n";
  cout << "Правила\n";
  cout << "Грають два гравцi на полі 3х3\n";
  cout << "Виграє той хто складе виграшну комбiнацiю\n";
  cout << "Вигляд поля\n\n";
  int l = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      cout << " | " << l + 1 << ' ';
      table[i][j] = char(49 + l);
      l++;
    }
    cout << " | ";
    cout << endl;

  }
  cout << "\nДля ходу нажмiть номер клiтинки поля\n";
  cout << "Для того щоб почати гру введiть будь-яку клавiшу";

  _getch();
}
bool input() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      cout << " | " << table[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << " | ";
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
  if (step) {
    cout << "Ходить " << name1 << " : " << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Ходить " << name2 << " : " << endl;
  }
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  if (n < 1 || n > 9) {
    return false;
  }
  int i, j;

  if (n % 3 == 0) {
    j = n % 3 - 1;
    i = n / 3;
  }
  if (table[i][j] == 'o' || table[i][j] == 'x') {
    return false;
  }
  if (step) {
    table[i][j] = 'x';
    step = false;
  } else {
    table[i][j] = 'o';
    step = true;
  }
  return true;
}
bool win() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

    if ((table[i][0] == table[i][1]) && (table[i][0] == table[i][2]))
      return true;
    else
  if ((table[0][i] == table[1][i]) && (table[0][i] == table[2][i]))
    return true;
  else if ((table[0][0] == table[1][1]) && (table[0][0] == table[2][2]) || (table[0][2] == table[1][1]) && (table[0][2] == table[2][0]))
    return true;

  return false;
}

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
  instructions();
  system("cls");
  int i = 0;
  cout << "Введiть iм'я першого гравця" << endl;
  cin.getline(name1, 30);
  cout << "Введiть iм'я другого гравця" << endl;
  cin.getline(name2, 30);

  srand(time(NULL));
  if (rand() & 1) {
    step = true;
  } else {
    step = false;
  }

  while (!win()) {
    if (i == 9) {
      cout << "Нiчия!";
      _getch();
      return -1;
    }
    system("cls");
    if (!input()) {
      cout << "Ви ввели невiрнi дані повторіть" << endl;
      _getch();

    }
    i++;
  }
  system("cls");
  if (step) {
    cout << "Виграв: " << name2 << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Виграв: " << name1 << endl;
  }


  _getch();
  return 0;
}
```

не могу найти ошибку.

Comment: *"не могу найти ошибку"* -- даже под отладчиком не видите на какой строке падает?

Answer (score 3):

```
int i, j;
/* а если n % 3 != 0 ? */
if (n % 3 == 0) {
    j = n % 3 - 1;
    i = n / 3;
}
/* то здесь переменные j и i не инициализированы */
if( table[i][j] == 'o' || table[i][j] == 'x' ) {
```

---

P.S. Учитесь пользоваться разными инструментами, а не только кнопкой "собрать проект". Даже самый простой отладчик может сэкономить вам кучу времени:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как исправит, понять не могу

Comment: всё нашол,спасиба

Answer (score 0):

Вместо этого

> `if (n % 3 == 0) {
>       j = n % 3 - 1;
>       i = n / 3;
>     }`

Должно быть

```
i = n / 3;
j = n % 3;
```